# Пример с пост- и пре-инкрементом

Tags: java, c#, c++, c, инкремент

```
int i = 0;
++i == i++; //true
i++ == i++; //false
```

Я знаю, что в случае пре-инкремента значение сначала увеличивается, а потом используется в выражении, а в случае пост-инкремента - наоборот. Но вот данный пример не могу понять.

Спасибо @AnT и @Grundy. Я понял, что в *С/С++* поведение не определено. А что в случае с *Java*?

Comment: _данный пример не могу понять_, попробуй переписать его исходя из того, что _в случае пре-инкремента значение сначала увеличивается, а потом используется в выражении, а в случае пост-инкремента наоборот_

Comment: Ну и в зависимости от реализации результаты могут отличаться от того, что приведен в вопросе.

Comment: @Grundy что Вы имеете ввиду под _реализацией_? В различных языках или различных компиляторах?

Comment: _В различных языках или различных компиляторах?_ и в различных языках, и, возможно, в различных компиляторах

Comment: в яве, например, порядок вычисления операндов строго определен (слева направо), а в c++ - нет.

Comment: @zRrr что? http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @Suvitruf то https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: @notaProgrammer, пример на c++ https://ideone.com/ZxNW5m возвращает `0,0`, что в принципе - false, false

Comment: Что это за сборная солянка языков? Вы собрали в одну кучу совершенно разные языки с совершенно разными поведениями.

Comment: @AnT, возможно было предположение, что из-за одинакового синтаксиса будет одинаковое поведение

Comment: Что такое `i`? Какой тип оно имеет?

Comment: Для [tag:c#] поведение должно быть определено

Comment: @AnT обновил вопрос. Если честно думал, что поведение в разных языках будет одинаково.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом выражении допустим значение `i` = 1, тогда получится

`++i == i++`, здесь выходит что слева сначала делается инкремент а потом возвращается значение, получается в первой части выражения получается 2, как Вы сами сказали, что посткремент сначала возвращает значение, а потом увеличивает, то он сначала вернет значение 2, получается что сравниваем `2 == 2`, по-этому `true`.

Второй вариант

`i++ == i++`, здесь тот же принцип, сначала оценивается левая часть выражения, мы получаем 1 и потом увеличиваем его, в итоге два в памяти, а в выражении 1, далее идет оценка правой части выражения, принцип тот же, получаем уже 2, потому что прошлый инкремент увеличил число, возвращаем 2 в выражение и увеличиваем ее, в памяти уже 3, а в выражении 2, в итоге сравниваем

`1 == 2`, это false

Надеюсь что ответил на Ваш вопрос

Вот ссылки на спецификацию java, во всех подобных языках оно будет работать так же

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2

Comment: А почему в первом варианте должно быть 2 == 2, а не 3 == 2? Если предположить, что `++i` возвращает `i`, и `i++` меняет `i`, тогда при сравнении слева должно быть измененное значение `i`, То есть `3`, а не 2.

Comment: ++i возвращает i + 1, а i++ сначала возвращает i, а потом делает + 1, но в выражении остается i

Comment: А точно ли `++i` возвращает `i+1`, а не сначала увеличивает `i` и возвращает именно `i`? Если считать что перед выполнением `==` выполнится `i++`, и само значение `i` так же поменяется тогда слева `i` Должно увеличиться дважды.

Comment: Было бы здорово добавить какие-нибудь ссылки на документацию для конкретных языков. На сколько я понимают в данном ответе тоже речь только про java, c#? Стоит добавить это непосредственно в ответ

Comment: он берет значение i, увеличивает его, а потом возвращает уже увеличенное значение, это точно, мой пример для Java, не могу знать как в C# или C++/C, но в Java/Js/Php оно работает так, в Java это в JLS прописано. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1 и вот еще https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2

Comment: Здорово! Добавь ссылки в ответ

Answer (score 6):

Ваш вопрос бессмыслен для любого языка программирования, если не известно, что такое `i`.

В языках С и С++, в предположении, что `i` - это некий объект скалярного типа, поведение этих выражений не определено. Никаких осмысленных результатов ваши выражения не порождают. Нет никакого смысла анализировать результаты бессмысленных выражений - они не подчиняются никакой логике.

Answer (score 4):

Для C# и Java: если сначала `i == 3` в одном и в другом случаях, то соответственно имеем

```
++i == i++; // ++i: увеличиваем i на 1, возвращается i (4), (i == 4)
            // i++: возвращается i (4), а потом увеличивается i на 1, (i ==5)
            // получаем 4 == 4 true

i++ == i++; // i++: возвращается i (3), а потом увеличивается i на 1, (i == 4)
            // ++i: возвращается i (4), а потом увеличивается i на 1, (i == 5)
            // получаем 3 == 4 false
```

Comment: Для каких из указанных в тегах языков верны данные рассуждения?

Comment: С#, Java, а про C и C++ уже выше написано

Comment: Стоит добавить это в сам ответ

Comment: @Grundy Добавил, надеюсь, автор ответа не возражает.